# how can i make this javascript function emit to a newline

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

okay I have an a script running that process a lot of data basically I am using the line below

```
 document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(stringbuild.hello);
```

problem is every time this line is send to message textbox it just overwrites the previous line from a previous output .

how can I make each output emit to a new empty line and keep any other previous data in the textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `<textbox>` use `\n` which is a newline character:

```
node = document.getElementById("message");
node.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(stringbuild.hello) + '\n';
```

Don't use `<br />` in a `<textbox>`.

And add it always at the end of the line, or you'll have the first line being empty.

Comment: this is only outputting the first line and nothing else after

Comment: fixed it it was my own fault also my output is line so "\"output\""
but I just want it to be output. how do I fix this so it removes "\" and \"" from the out put

Comment: I want to help you but I have a hard time understanding the problem. can you please add some code to your question?

Comment: basically when I get the output in the message box each string is wrapped with "\" and \""  is there a way I can remove it

Comment: try `stringbuild.hello.substring(1, stringbuild.hello.length - 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

If the 'message' element is a regular HTML element (e.g. a [`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)), try would work:

```
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += "<br>" + JSON.stringify(stringbuild.hello);
```

- The [`+=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) is an '[augmented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_assignment)' assignment operator which appends the current string with whatever value is provided to the right.
- The [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) is an html line break character, used to make place the the new string directly underneath the previous string.

For an input element [`<input type="text">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) or [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea), use this:

```
document.getElementById("message").value += "\n" + JSON.stringify(stringbuild.hello);
```

- The `value` property is used to access the current value of the input element, and should be used instead of `innerHTML`.
- The `\n` is the [escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Using_special_characters_in_strings) for a new line character.

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/thx7n/2/)

Comment: unfortunately this does not work its just included within the string

Comment: @user3385289 See my updated answer for additional information.

Comment: fixed it it was my own fault also my output is line so "\"output\"" but I just want it to be output. how do I fix this so it removes "\" and \"" from the out put

Comment: @p.s.w.g I removed my comment, it was out of line. I got kind of carried away :)

Comment: @user3385289 Well, it's not entirely clear what you need to do. You could try simply removing call to `JSON.stringify`, or use `str.substr(1, str.length - 2)` to remove the first and last character from the string.